# Custome Animation for bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I try to achieve the Given view here for the bottom navigation bar, I know how I can animate the Icons and the background with their size, but I have no idea how I can achieve The Animation and the view of the Arc above the Selected Icon, Any Ideas how I can implement this behaviour and this Custome View?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Surface` component takes a shape parameter. You could try implementing a Shape that creates the desired outline for the background based on the icon position and update the shape as the icon moves.